# Infer return type of generic function

Tags: c++

Currently I have to use `auto x = Console::Get()->Find<int>("int");` to get the value of the `CVar` with name "int".

What I am trying to achieve is to call `Find` without specifying a type.

Example:

- `auto x = Console::Get()->Find("int");` (x is an int).
- `auto y = Console::Get()->Find("variableWithBoolType");` (y is a bool).

Is this even possible?

```cpp
#include <any>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

template<typename T>
class CVar;

class Console {
    using TRegistryMap = std::unordered_map<std::string_view, std::any>;

public:
    Console();

    static Console *Get() { return m_Instance; }

    template<typename T>
    void Register(CVar<T> *var) {
        Registry()[var->m_Name] = var;
    }

    template<typename T>
    auto Find(const std::string &name) {
        return std::any_cast<CVar<T> *>(Registry()[name])->Get();
    }

private:
    static TRegistryMap &Registry() {
        static TRegistryMap impl;
        return impl;
    }

    static Console *m_Instance;

};

Console* Console::m_Instance = nullptr;

Console::Console() {
    m_Instance = this;
}

template<typename T>
class CVar
{
public:
    CVar(std::string name, T value, std::string noexcept
        : m_Name(std::move(name))
        , m_Value(value)
        , m_Help(std::move(help))
    {
        Console::Get()->Register(this);
    }

    [[nodiscard]] const std::string &GetName() const { return m_Name; }

    [[nodiscard]] const auto &Get() const { return m_Value; }

    void Set(T value) const { m_Value = value; }

    [[nodiscard]] const std::string &GetHelp() const { return m_Help; }

public:
    std::string m_Name;
    mutable T m_Value;
    std::string m_Help;

};

static const CVar GCVarInt(
    "int",
    1000,
    "Test int CVar"
);

static const CVar GCVarString(
    "string",
    "test",
    "Test string CVar"
);

int main() {
    std::cout << GCVarInt.GetName() << " -> " << GCVarInt.Get() << '\n';

    auto x = Console::Get()->Find<int>("int");
    std::cout << x << '\n';
    GCVarInt.Set(500);
    x = Console::Get()->Find<int>("int");
    std::cout << x << '\n';
    
    auto y = Console::Get()->Find<const char *>("string");
    std::cout << y << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*Is this even possible?*" - not the way you have presented it, no. If you don't want to specify the template parameter explicitly, you'll have to use an output parameter passed by reference/pointer instead, so the compiler can deduce the template parameter based on the type of variable passed, eg: `int x; Console::Get()->Find(..., &x);`

Answer (score 2):

The type of a variable in C++ is a compile-time computed value.

The information stored in the strings `"int"` or `"variableWithBoolType"` are run-time values.

You cannot use run-time values to compute compile-time computed values.

There are exceptions.

C++ supports compile time strings.  With a compile time string variable, you could *in theory* extract type information in an earlier registration.  But even here, it would have to be a type registration *performed in the same compilation unit*, as compile-time computation *cannot cross compilation unit boundaries*, nor can it use information after the line being compiled to change the result on the line being compiled.

As a second choice, you could simply not use a string there.  And that token could embed the type in it at the point it is declared.

As a third choice, you could return something like a variant or any.  Then the user of the variable can switch on the actual type.

As a forth choice, you could ship a complete C++ implementation, generate information needed by the situation based on runtime information about the string, recompile it and produce a dynamically linked library, load that dynamically linked library with static type information, and run it.

Now, all of these are possible, none of these are easy, and almost certainly none of these are the easiest solution to your underlying problem.

You appear to be at the point where you should reconsider using C++, or reconsider your approach, as your approach is frankly hostile to C++'s assumptions.  Have you considered a nice scripting language?  They do away with compile time types (usually entirely), so this technique isn't at all alien to them.

Alternatively, this could be a simple X/Y problem.  You have some underlying problem X.  You come up with a solution Y that would solve your underlying problem, except you want this 'minor' feature of being able to generate types based on `"strings like this"`.  And you then ask about that 'minor' feature, not suspecting that it isn't possible in C++.  Meanwhile, the underlying problem X can be solved in C++.

The issue here is that there are a bunch of things you can do in C++ that are **adjacent** to what you describe in very specific ways that are insanely easier (and/or possible), but I have no idea if any of them apply.  And you don't know enough C++ to ask that question.

Note that if you asked about X, quite possibly someone would know how to solve it.